# how to use jsx inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an object inside an array like this:

```
const anyThing = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "alberteinstein1879",
        message: `e=mc${<sup>2</sup>}`,
    }
]
```

But when I run this it shows `e=mc[object Object]`

Comment: Just use the unicode _superscript 2_ (`U+00B2`):`e=mc²`

Comment: `message: `<>e=mc<sup>2</sup></>`

Comment: Possibly an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Why do you want to do this in the first place? Usually JSX stays in the `render`/`return` and the raw data stays in object/array data structures.

Comment: @ggorlen ok now what should I do in this case? personally using Unicode seems fine but I don't know how I should do it

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001031/how-to-use-jsx-inside-javascript-object?noredirect=1#comment130661395_74001031) @saleh Just copy from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001031/how-to-use-jsx-inside-javascript-object?noredirect=1#comment130661203_74001031) and paste into your string literal. Stack Overflow made an actual [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) to make it even easier for cases like these.

Comment: @jsejcksn huh thank you, didn't realize I can copy the actual letter lol

Answer (score 0):

You can just put is like this:
`<>e=mc<sup>2</sup></>`
and have all the additional text between the `<>` tags.